# Grails enum ordinal

Tags: grails, groovy, enums

I've an enum like:

```
enum Color {
  RED("Red color"),
  GREEN("green color")

  String color
  Color(String color) {
    this.color = color
  }
}
```

and a domain:

```
class MyDomain {
  String name
  Color color

  static mapping = {
    color enumType: "ordinal", sqlType: "tinyint"
  }
}
```

However, we I tried to insert a new data into the database, I got an error like

```
default message [Could not find matching constructor for: Color(java.lang.Integer)]
```

I understand that I don't have a constructor with an integer, but I want to store the index of each color in order to avoid repetition. How can I solve it?

Comment: Have a constructor with an `int`. You should read the doc of `ordinal()`, which makes it clear that you shouldn't use it except for its intended purpose (of which this is not an example).

Comment: It looks like your `mapping` may be incorrect - what is `look` referring to?

Comment: looks like premature optimization to me. Use normal string-valued enums and don't fix, what is not broken